# Why does Dumbledore trust Snape?

Tags: harry-potter, severus-snape

Snape was once a Death Eater. After Voldemort killed Lily, Snape joined the team of Dumbledore. Fine. They also worked together for years. Fine Again. But, what made Dumbledore think that he could trust Snape after his death? Prior to Dumbledore's death, loyalty of Snape could be because of fear of Dumbledore or benefits of returns like protection against Voldemort or his job. But, what made Dumbledore think that an ex-evil guy would remain loyal to him after his death?

Comment: Technically he turned against Voldemort before Lily died. The moment he realised Voldemort interpreted what he heard to be the Potters he went to Dumbledore to protect - at first only Lily - the Potters (again because of his love for Lily). And evil is a strong word. Complicated man, yes, but not evil.

Answer (score 1):

The loyalty of Snape was based on his love for Lily, and consequent hatred for Voldemort after him killing her. Dumbledore saw this, and trusted that in the end Snape's love for Lily would keep him fighting against Voldemort.